# Prove that $\mathbb P(X_1,X_2)^{-1}=\mathbb P_1X_1^{-1}\otimes \mathbb P_2X_2^{-1}$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)=(\Omega _1\times \Omega _2,\mathcal F_1\otimes \mathcal F_2,\mathbb P_1\otimes \mathbb P_2)$ a probability space (where $(\Omega _i,\mathbb F_i,\mathbb P_i)$ are probability spaces). Let $f_i:\Omega _i\to \mathbb R$ measurable and $\pi_i:\Omega \to \Omega _i$ the natural projection on $\Omega _i$. Let $$X_i(\omega _1,\omega _2)=f_i\circ \pi_i(\omega _1,\omega _2)=f_i(\omega _i).$$

Prove that $$\mathbb P(X_1,X_2)^{-1}=P_1X_1^{-1}\otimes P_2X_2^{-1}\tag{1}$$

It's enough to prove that (1) hold on $$\{A_1\times A_2\mid A_i\in \mathcal F_i\}.$$

So \begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X_1,X_1)^{-1}(A_1\times A_2)&=\mathbb P\{(X_1,X_2)\in A_1\times A_2\}\\
&=\mathbb P(\{X_1\in A_1\}\times \{X_2\in A_2\})\\
&=\mathbb P_1\{X_1\in A_1\}\mathbb P_2\{X_2\in A_2\}\tag{*}\\
&=(\mathbb P_1X_1^{-1}\otimes \mathbb P_2X_2^{-1})(A_1\times A_2).
\end{align*}
**Question**

Where did I used the fact that $X_i=f_i\circ \pi_i$ ?

Comment: In equality $(*)$ that I added in your post). Indeed, $$\{X_i\in A_i\}=\{\omega\in \Omega _i\mid f_i(\omega )\in A_i\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You used the fact that $X_i=f_i\circ \pi_i$ when you wrote
$$\mathbb P\{(X_1,X_2)\in A_1\times A_2\}=\mathbb P_1\{X_1\in A_1\}\mathbb P_2\{X_2\in A_2\}$$

because $(X_1,X_2)(\omega_1,\omega_2) \in A_1\times A_2$ if and only if $f_i(w_i) \in A_i$, i.e. if and only if $\omega_i \in f_i^{-1}(A_i)$, thus you have that $\{(X_1,X_2)\in A_1\times A_2\}=f_1^{-1}(A_1) \times f_2^{-1}(A_2)$.

Furthermore note that $\mathbb P(\{X_1\in A_1\})=\mathbb P (\{\omega_1: f_1(\omega_1) \in A_1\} \times \Omega_2)=\mathbb P_1 (f_1 \in A_1)$ and then you get what you want (noting the same thing for $i=2$).

**Remark:** note also that $\{X_1\in A_1\}\times \{X_2\in A_2\} \subset \Omega \times \Omega$ and not $\{X_1\in A_1\}\times \{X_2\in A_2\} \subset \Omega=\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ thus you cannot write $\mathbb P(\{X_1\in A_1\}\times \{X_2\in A_2\})$